# Reading a file which a white spaces every where till it reads where there is no more character to read

Tags: java, string, file-io, whitespace

I have to read a file which have strings which are separated by white spaces. But there are multiple white spaces and it should be read and shown it in to jtext area in swing. But really does n't know how to solve this problem using scanner and string delimiter.

inputfile.txt

```
hello good 

hello good 

hello bye 

great 

hello good 

hello bye great 

hello bye 

great 

hello bye great 

hello bye 

good 



hello 

good 

hello bye good 

hello good 

good 

great 



good 

hello good 

bye 



hello 

hello bye 

hello bye great 

hello great 

bye 

bye 

good great 

great 

great 

bye 

bye
```

code that i tried

```
 BufferedReader br12=new BufferedReader(new FileReader("input.txt"));  
String s4;    
        while((s4=br12.readLine())!=null)
        {
            int j=1;


            StringTokenizer st11=new StringTokenizer(s4);
            while(st11.hasMoreTokens())
            {
                String bb1=st11.nextToken();
                if(j==1)
                {
                   // bw.write(bb+" ");
                    jTextArea1.append(bb1+" ");
                }
                j++;
            }
```

Comment: Post some code so we can help you out

Comment: I think you want to read the above chat and show in the JTextArea, right ?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma posted the code which i have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
  File file = new File("path to your file");

try {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(file);
    String line = null;
    while (sc.hasNextLine()) {
       line = sc.nextLine();
        jTextArea1.append(line+"\n");
    }
    sc.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: YOUR_textArea.append(line+"\n") so that every line is on new row in textarea.